# Преобразование массива без цикла

Tags: python, numpy

Необходимо имеющийся массив типа float преобразовать в пропорциональный, где min исходного соответствует числу 0 в новом массиве. 0 в исходном соответствует 0,5. Max исходного - соответствует 1. Нужно получить новый массив со значениями от 0 до 1 пропорциональный исходному. При том, не хотелось бы использовать очевидное решение с циклом.

```
def interpol(output, min_v, max_v):
    if output < 0:
        result = (output - min_v)/(0-min_v)*0.5
    else:
        result = 0.5+(output/max_v)*0.5
    return result
```

Были мысли о map, но никак из-за дополнительных параметров. Может есть какое элегантное решение?

Comment: зачем это (без цикла)? И, кстати, это точно массив или всё же обычный список?

Comment: Массив может быть очень большим, а встроенные операции NumPy гораздо быстрее работают чем циклы.

Comment: а ничего, что у вас про `NumPy` ни слова ни в вопросе, ни в тегах?:-)

Comment: Исправляюсь, добавил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто использовать встроенную функцию  np.where для условия:

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([-3,-1,0,7,9])
min_a=np.min(a)
max_a=np.max(a)
ans=np.where(a<=0, (min_a-a)*.5/min_a, a*.5/max_a+.5 )
print(ans)
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, как-то так:

```
arr = list(range(50, 100))

# я так понимают мин  и макс вы так получать будете
min_v = min(arr)
max_v = max(arr)

new_arr = list(map(lambda x: interpol(x, min_v, max_v), arr))
print(new_arr)
```

Comment: `list(map(lambda x: ..., arr)` намекают на `[... for x in arr]`. (* позже заметил что ТС просит лямбду).

Comment: Получаю решение 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable. Переводил map в массив следующим образом: `np.fromiter((map(lambda x: interpol(x, min_v, max_v), svm_values)), dtype=np.float64)`

Comment: @АнтонЩербаков потому `np.fromiter(map(lambda x: interpol(x, min_v, max_v), svm_values), dtype=np.float64)`

Answer (score 1):

Так как это оказалось NumPy, то надо делать средствами NumPy. Получившееся функция обрабатывает как отдельные значения так и массивы любой размерности:

```
import numpy as np


def interpol(x, min_v, max_v):
    # как же я люблю эту нотацию!
    pieces = (
        (x <  0, lambda x: -x / min_v),
        (x >= 0, lambda x:  x / max_v)
    )
    return (1 + np.piecewise(x, *zip(*pieces))) / 2


x = np.linspace(-2, 4, num=7, endpoint=True)
print(x)
print(interpol(x, -2, 4))
```

> ```
> $ py numpy-example.py 
> [-2. -1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
> [0.    0.25  0.5   0.625 0.75  0.875 1.   ]
> ```

Если средствами чистого Питона, то труба пониже и дым пожиже. Создание интерполятора отделено от использования:

```
def make_interpol(min_v, max_v):

    def interpol(output):
        if output < 0:
            result = (output - min_v)/(0-min_v)*0.5
        else:
            result = 0.5+(output/max_v)*0.5
        return result 

    return interpol


interpol = make_interpol(min_v, max_v)
map(interpol, arr)
```